# common runonUIthread for whole application

Tags: android, multithreading, design-patterns

So, I am designing an android application that interacts with some hardware over a bluetooth dongle.

The request/response model is a little slow (sometimes it takes 1-2 seconds to receive a response to a particular request) and hence I have kept the request sent and response received model in a different thread.

To achieve the same I have created an interface `ResultPoster` with some callback methods like `onMyResponse()`.

This interface is implemented by various `Activity` and UI components of my application, but as we know that we simply can't post to **UI or Main** thread directly from another thread therefore I use `runOnUIthread` in all the UI components (Activities or Fragments basically).

e.g.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
stopProgressDialog();
launchActivity();
}
});
```

There are a lot of such blocks present in my code now and they are increasing as some logic gets complex.

**Now, I want to keep my code clean and create a bridge throughout the application that will help me to post results over to UI from another thread, just based upon the `context` that I am into. 
Can you suggest me some other approach ?**

-Edit-

**Is this an overkill to use multiple such code blocks in various Activities to achieve the same ?**

Comment: it's very easy. make one common Parent Activity. extends each of your activity to this activity and used Activity as a Context to every where. or you can do the same in different seprate Bean class by using Activity context

Comment: @MD Let's say I have created a ParentActivity that will be extended by all of my Application Activities. But still , I will have to use a `runOnUIThread` method inside these activities ? Or we are talking about keeping only one `runOnUIthread` inside ParentActivity ? How would the context be passed in this case , where ?

Answer (score 8):

You could create a custom Application class in which you create some kind of runOnUiThread method yourself.

It would look something like this:

```
/**
 * @author Dirk Vranckaert
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public static final void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
            runnable.run();
        } else {
            mHandler.post(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Then from any class in your application you should be able to call MyApplication.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {..});

If you could be using lambdas this would even look a lot nicer.
But you get the idea, you just have convenience method in your custom Application class and can call it from anywhere.

Comment: So basically I have one runOnUIthread method but multiple `new Runnable` codes ?

Comment: Yes. This means that from anywhere you want (even if you don't have a context) you can com back from your background thread and make sure the code is getting executed on your main thread.
As I mentioned, if you start getting to use lambdas your code will look a lot cleaner as you can call this method with a lambda.

Comment: It is possible to configure your Android project to start using lambdas already with a compatibility library. It's explained over here: http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html
What is does, you write lambdas and the compiler puts back the plain old object creation with implementation of the method inline. That's basically it, so no runtime improvement, but cleaner code anyway!